# Issue reading data from sharedpreferences. I have to run the app twice before it gets the data stored

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an issues reading from sharedpreferences in android. The data is stored in the preference file, and i ma sure of this because i used logcat to log the data when i read it back IMMEDIATELY as it was stored as well as i used a toast message to display the data after i  read it back from preferences. However when i try to read the data again from a new activity it returns the default of an empty sting. When i exist the app and run it again it read the data that was previously stored. Here is my code for when i initially save the data, it also contains the comments i used to verify that the data stored was read back:

```
public void downloadMatchesAsync() {

    brawtaAPIAdapter.runGetMatches(new Callback<JSONKeys>() {

        @Override
        public void success(JSONKeys jsonKeys, Response response) {
            Log.d(ApplicationConstants.TAG, "blarg");
            Success = jsonKeys.isSuccess();
            message = jsonKeys.getErrorMessage().toString();

            if(!message.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), message,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonObject = gson.toJson(jsonKeys); //converts java object into json string'


            Preferences.saveToPreferences(activity, ApplicationConstants.match_data, jsonObject);
            //data =Preferences.readFromPreferences(activity, ApplicationConstants.match_data, "no data");
            //Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "In networkOperation" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    }); // Call Async API

    //return data;
}
```

In a different activity i try to read the data previously written like so:

```
  jsonString = Preferences.readFromPreferences(MatchSelect.this, ApplicationConstants.match_data, "");
```

but the code only returns the data stored if i exist the app and run it again.

this is my preference class:

```
   public class Preferences {

private static final String PrefName = "net.brawtasports.brawtasportsgps";

public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);

}
```

}

What is the issue?

Comment: What does the `Preferences` class look like? If you are having trouble writing data to `SharedPreferences`, showing where you write the data is important to understanding the problem.

Comment: just added the other class

Comment: did you call commit() ?

Comment: i tried commit(), but that did not work.

Comment: i uninstall the application off the device and ran it again with the commit statement but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

`apply()` is an asynchronous call, so the data doesn't have to be stored immediately. Try calling `.commit()` instead.

Comment: like i said the data was saved because i was able to read it back immediately after i saved it. it just not not being read immediately from the second activity unless i run the app twice.

Comment: could it be that you start a new activity before your 'success' call is done (which means before the data is saved?)

Comment: that sounds like it could be the cause. not sure though. i called the read function in the second activity's oncreate method but it still puzzles my why it was stored to begin with yet not displayed when the second activity is called